# OSX Rcpp & sourceCpp() errors

Tags: macos, rcpp

I had no Rcpp errors until upgrading (from 3.1 or 3.2) to 3.2.3 on my Mac.  Something broke and I have no idea how to fix it.  I hope the snapshot below is sufficient.

```
Microsoft R Open 3.2.3

Error in sourceCpp("MyTestCode2.cpp") : 
Error 1 occurred building shared library.

clang: 
WARNING: The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found.  
Please install Command Line Tools for XCode (or equivalent).

error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libcairo.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libpixman-1.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libfreetype.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libreadline.a'
make: *** [sourceCpp_1.so] Error 1**
```

Xcode 7.2.1 is installed as are the command line tools (7.2).  I am stumped. My son now has the same problem on his Macbook after downloading Revolution R 3.2.3.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you ask the good folks at Microsoft / Revolution per

> Microsoft R Open 3.2.3

as our package works on all CRAN platforms, see [here](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_Rcpp.html) for the nightly tests results including two different OS X setups.

I also suggest that you (subscribe to first if needed) post on the [rcpp-devel](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/mailman/listinfo/rcpp-devel) list where a number of OS X users participate.  I am more pedestrian myself as a Linux user...

Comment: Will do.  Everything works if I remove the Mr Softie version and use regular R 3.2.3.   I can get the MSFT version to work on Windoze, but not OSX.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by a simple 'brew install cairo' on OSX - not sure why Rcpp depends on cairo, but it should be added to the dependencies of both Rcpp & ROpen to avoid this issue.